# Is it common to have a function parameter as Action<T> instead of T only, and why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, function-parameter

**Simply**: I have noticed, that in ASP.NET Core MVC application, parameters to some functions use typically type `Action<T>` instead of type `T`. It is a bit strange, where can I found more info about that?

**Example**:

```
services.AddDbContext<FssDbContext>(options => 
  options.UseSqlServer(-something-));
```

**More detailed**:
I am a newbie in ASP.NET Core, but not in .NET. I am working now on web ASP.NET Core MVC project and I have noticed that many function calls have as a parameter a `System.Action<T>` instead of `T` directly. I suppose that this is somehow closely related to DI and "not let the code-user creates an instance, but provide him some to adjust", but I'd like to know more info about that - especially if this is a common approach in .NET MVC/Core and where it should be used (and where is it not suggested), or even if it is some well-known defined concept I am missing.

However, I am not able to find anything about that, just the simple usages.

Is there any resource describing this behaviour, motivation, and suggestions?

Again, I am not interested "how can I create such behaviour", as I am not interested in "generic opinions", but if there is some official definition of this concept or globally well-known advice "where (/if) am I supposed to use it in .NET MVC/Core project" (e.g. from MS)?

Comment: Basically, it's about using a "fluent" style of configuration. Using `Action<T>` where `T` has methods that return `T`, you can chain your method calls together, building the configuration options (in the example in your question) easily.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately much of this looks to be opinion-based and thus off-topic. While a question about the difference and purpose behind `System.Action<T>` instead of just `T` would probably be OK, all the inquiries about best practices, common approaches, etc. are off-topic and risk this question being closed. I'd recommend removing that content from the question to ensure it stays open.

Comment: They use that action because the author of that method liked that syntax, or it was a decision by the team, or whatnot. What it boils down to is that someone decided that this was the way they wanted to design it, in other words, someone's *opinion* was that ... Thus, this question is asking either for their opinion or what our opinion on why this might be is.

Comment: It's not **that** opinion based. To have `T` as an argument, you have to have `T` at the very moment. On the other hand, having `Action<T>` means `T` can be obtained anywhere **in future** and passed to this function. Assuming the config is done somewhere at the beginning of the pipeline, it's much more natural to expect actions because the underlying actual elements of the infrastructure can be created later.

Comment: @TylerH Thank's for advice. I didn't mean to ask for somebody's ideas or common experience, but about some official document or the globally-stated well-known methodology, e.g. from Microsoft, as it looks to be a commonly used concept.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, I see that the "Fluent Interface" might be what I am looking for.

Comment: With respect to the other commenters, I don't think you should be looking up "fluent interfaces" for this one. I think you should be looking for "inversion of control" instead.

Comment: (@Nkosi: thanks for the edits to this question. However, I'd point out that "behaviour" is a legitimate spelling, it's British English. We have a long-standing convention that all kinds of English spellings are accepted here `:-)`. I have switched them back.)

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not familiar enough with ASP.NET to give you a full answer.*

I can tell you that having `Action<T>` as parameter means that the library is ensuring you will pass something they can call. It is a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

They will be using it to give you a `T` object. Why would they do it (instead of, you know, returning `T` or using an `out` parameter)? Perhaps they need to do some clean up after you run your code, for example they will be catching exceptions, doing synchronization, disposing resources... something like that.

Another advantage of using a callback is that the library controls whatever or not you run the code. If they gives you a `T` object (and perhaps a `bool` to tell you to run your code), you might just ignore them.

It could also be that the code there is meant to run in a particular thread, it might even be that they will be running it in the future as the need arises, perhaps even multiple times. In fact, they can use it similar to an event, except you cannot subscribe and unsubscribe at arbitrary times.